# Scam input token cannot be transferred on Uniswap

Tags: tokens, uniswap

I've been seeing this pop up quite a bit recently. Scammer creates a ERC token with the name of something popular - Shiba or Kishu. Adds alot of liquidity to the pool but once you buy the token you cannot swap it back for any other token. Eventually they drain the liquidity pool and repeat.

You receive the error: "The input token cannot be transferred. There may be an issue with the input token."

Is there any solution to this for those that have been affected before the pool is drained?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a place to learn more about these verification efforts?

Answer (score 2):

No, if a scammer creates a bad token and you buy it, there is usually nothing you can do to get your money back.  You always need to be careful and double-check the addresses of the smart contracts and tokens you are interacting with.  Be careful about fake Uniswap websites also.  Using multiple sources of information can help improve your confidence.